# Mapping a map collection containing superclasses in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, polymorphism, hibernate-xml-mapping

I am trying to map a map collection of **String**, **SuperClass** using XML mapping files. Here's what I have:

```xml
<map name="mapName" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
    <key column="ID" />
    <index column="KEY" type="string" />
    <one-to-many class="SuperClass" />
</map>
```

The SuperClass has (currently one but probably going to need some more in the future) a subclass that I'm going to call SubClass. So I have a bunch of SubClass and SuperClass objects in the map and when Hibernate attempts to search for them after adding them I get a

> org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

I'm pretty sure Hibernate is looking for classes of type **SuperType** when the objects in the map actually have some **SubType**s as well.

Here's the gist of how the mapping was done for the hierarchy in case you need a better representation of what I'm talking about:

```xml
<class name="SuperClass" table="SUPER_CLASS">
    ...properties...
    (contains some <component> tags as well if it matters)
    <union-subclass name="SubClass" table="SUBCLASS">
        ...more properties...
    </union-subclass>
</class>
```